# Power Bi: Createa a sum measure conditional on all three rows being present

Tags: powerbi

For ease of understanding, the table has 3 columns: (Date, Item, Value). I want to add a conditional aspect to my calculate-sum measure to only sum when Item 1 is present. Right now Item 3 is a row that is sometimes present by itself but I don't want that as it's a false-positive for my data set.

**Current:**

```
Measure = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Values]),

FILTER('Table',
'Table'[Item] = "Item 1" ||
'Table'[Item] = "Item 2" ||
'Table'[Item] = "Item 3" 
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column, to make the value 0 for all other cases except Item1:

```
Column = IF(Table[Item]="C",Table[value],0)
```

Now you can sum up this column to get the results you are looking for.

Edit based on Comment:

```
    Check_Column = 
         VAR Step1=CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Item]),CALCULATETABLE('Table',ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Month]),'Table'[Item]<>"C"))
         VAR Step2 = IF(Step1=BLANK(),0,'Table'[Value])
    Return Step2
```

The above calculation will not count any record which has only a value of C.You can simply sum up the column to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry I realized I phrased my statement a bit ambigiguously. I still want Item 3 to show value when Item 1 has a value, but if-only-if Item 1 is present. The harder part for me to wrap my head around is that Item 1 only has a database row when it has a value, so it doesnt exist when there's no value for that Item in any given month.

Comment: Can you share a sample data from the table and the desired output for that data?

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable about sharing data properly, but maybe this will work?  <https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKZ9a.png>

Comment: That makes it much clearer. I have added an edit to accommodate your request...Try it and let me know if it works...

Comment: So I added the column but assume I'm not doing something correct as the ouput for the excluded item still shows a value. I was wondering if its because I would need to reference 3 columns instead of just the month columns (also customer number and Year).  Hopefully this data picture can help.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV3ZL.png

Comment: Hi Eric, based on the previous screenshot you shared, it looked like you did not want to count only when the month does not have any other items other than C...That's what the formula is doing...If you just want to remove all the Items "C", the first formula would work